# Node.js write function doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, android, node.js

I'm trying to send data to a client, but it doesn't seem to work I am not receiving any data on client side. Sending data only works when I use `write` outside callback function. Does someone have an idea?

```
var server = _net.createServer(function (socket) {
  var translater = {
    getSocket: function () {
      return socket;
    }
  };
  socket.on('data', function (data) {
    _db.save_callback(data, function (result) {
      if (result) {
        var re = translater.getSocket().write("ok");
        if (re)
          console.log('send ok...');
        else console.log('send not_ok...');
      }
    });
  });
  socket.on('end', function () {
    console.log('client disconnected');
  });
  //socket.pipe(socket);
});
```

This is my Client side code

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
 {
    try
      {
         InetAddress serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(Preferences.SERVER_ADDRESS);
            _socket = new Socket(serverAddress,
                Preferences.SERVER_PORT);
            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
              _socket.getOutputStream()));
            printWriter = new PrintWriter(bufferedWriter,true);
            printWriter.println(params[0]);

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
              _socket.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String response = "";
            while((response = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                stringBuilder.append(response);
                Log.i(TAG, "Response: " + response);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            printWriter.close();
            try {
                _socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            printWriter.close();
            _socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add your client-side code?

Comment: Hello @MattSchofield, i just added my client side code

Comment: What happens if you call `write()` directly on `socket`, without going through `translater.getSocket()`? You should be able to refer to `socket` directly; it's in scope.

Comment: @MattSchofield when i refer to socket directly im still not receiving data on client side

Comment: Are you able to push data up the socket to your server? I'm not 100% sure, but you don't seem to have any concept of `connection`s in your code, so I'm wondering if you'd need to establish one and then listen for the `data` event on the `connection`, not the `socket`...?

Comment: @MattSchofield yes i am receiving data on the server. when i use socket outside the callback function socket.write() i do get data on client side. I looks like the socket is out of scope in de callback function?

Comment: @MattSchofield and olso the socket.pipe() function should be uncommend before data reaches the client buffer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96037/discussion-between-matt-schofield-and-donnovan).